# How to get the code coverage required to deploy Apex Class

Tags: salesforce, apex

Please Help!!!
I have this Apex controller class that I'm trying to deploy from Salesforce Sandbox to Production but I'm not getting the code coverage required!!

the class is consuming 3 objects, one is stranded and 2 are custom and constructing a hierarchy tree view for those three objects.

//Apex Class

public class TeeView {

```
        /* Wrapper class to contain the nodes and their children */
 public class cNodes
{
    Public StandardObject gparent {get;set;}
    public List<CustomObject1__c> parent {get; set;}
    Public List<CustomObject2__c> child {get;set;}

    public cNodes(StandardObject   gp, List<CustomObject1__c> p, List<CustomObject2__c> c)
    {
    parent = p;
    gparent = gp;
    child = c;
    }
}

        /* end of Wrapper class */ 

Public List<cNodes> hierarchy;

Public List<cNodes> getmainnodes()
{
    hierarchy = new List<cNodes>();
    List<StandardObject> tempparent = [Select Id,Name  , End_Date__c, Owner.Name Account.Name from Contract ];
    for (Integer i =0; i< tempparent.size() ; i++)
        {
        List<CustomObject1__c> tempchildren = [Select Id,Name, Owner.Name , (select Id,Name, Owner.Name from CustomObject2__r)  from CustomObject1__c where    Related_Field__c = :tempparent[i].Id];
        List<CustomObject2__c> tempchild = [Select Id,Name Owner.Name from CustomObject2__c where    Related_Field__c= :tempparent[i].Id];

        hierarchy.add(new cNodes(tempparent[i],tempchildren, tempchild));
        }   
    return hierarchy;
}
```

}

//Test Class
@isTest
public class treeviewTest
{

```
static testMethod void test1()
{
    test.startTest();


    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Unit test account');
    insert acc;

    StandardObject c = new StandardObject(
        Name = 'test',
        AccountId = acc.Id,
        Status = 'Draft',
        StartDate = System.today());
    try
    {
        insert c;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
    }

    List<StandardObject> standard = [select Id, Name from StandardObject where Name = 'test'];
    system.assertequals(standard.size(), 1);

    CustomObject1__c s = new CustomObject1__c(
        Related_StandardObjectField__c = c.Id,
        Name = 'test'
    );
    try
    {
        insert s;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
    }

    List<CustomObject1__c> cus1 = [select Id, Name from CustomObject1__c where Name = 'test'];
    system.assertequals(cus1.size(), 1);

    insert new CustomObject2__c(Related_StandardObjectField__c = c.Id, Description__c = 'test');
    List<CustomObject2__c> cus2 = [select Id, Name from CustomObject2__c where Description__c = 'test'];
    system.assertequals(cus2.size(), 1);

    insert new CustomObject2__c(Related_CustomObject1Field__c = s.Id, Description__c = 'test');
    List<Mods__c> cus3 = [select Id, Name from Mods__c where Description__c = 'test'];
    system.assertequals(cus3.size(), 1);

    treeView view = new treeView();

    view.getmainnodes();


    test.stopTest();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, where do we even start... Looks like you copy-pasted some code at random trying to get the test to work? Your code works on `Contract, CustomObject1__c, CustomObject2__c`. Your unit test inserts `Contract, Subaward__c, Mods__c`. Was this some attempt at anonymizing your code? And what's this `List<StandardObject>` thing, it shouldn't even compile.

I think you need help of a developer with more experience, you've cobbled something together but it doesn't follow the Salesforce best practices for code...

**About the main class**

Smart use of [subqueries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm) will mean

- you waste less SOQL (it's bad idea to blindly select all records without any filters but whatever),
- don't run into errors related to "too many SOQL statements" (the limit is 100 so since you query in a loop - your code will crash and burn the moment you have around 50 Contracts)
- lead to compact code occupying less lines (easier to maintain & cover with tests).

I'd go with something like that, query Contract & first related list in one go and then the parents + children in another query. Using a `Map` to link them for displaying.

```
List<Contract> levelOneAndTwo = [SELECT Id, Name, End_Date__c, Owner.Name, Account.Name,
    (SELECT Id,Name, Owner.Name FROM Subawards__r)
FROM Contract];

Map<Id, SubAward__c> levelTwoAndThree = new Map<Id, Subaward__c>([SELECT Id,
    (SELECT Id,Name Owner.Name FROM Mods__r)
    FROM Subaward__c WHERE Contract__c = :levelOneAndTwo];
);
```

This wastes only 2 queries but fetches all contracts and their related data. Then you can loop over results building your wrapper object or just feed it directly to Visualforce for displaying.

**About the unit test**

You don't get the coverage because you're spread too thin. One unit test methods inserts only Contracts (so your main query will hit something, give you some coverage). Then another method (in completely different context) inserts some child objects - but they don't matter. In that other method there are 0 contracts so it won't even enter your main loop. Combine it into one?

```
Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Unit test account');
insert acc;

Contract c = new Contract(
    Name = 'test contract',
    AccountId = acc.Id,
    Status = 'Draft',
    StartDate = System.today()
);
insert c;

Subaward__c s = new Subaward(
    Contract__c = c.Id,
    Name = 'test'
);
insert s;

insert new Mod__c(Subaward__c = c.Id, Description__c = 'test');
```

Now you have nice tree hierarchy set up, from Account all the way down. Queries in the test should hit some data.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get %100 code coverage for the above class by adding these lines to the test class:

```
     treeView view = new treeView();
                view.getmainnodes();
                    system.assert(view.hierarchy.size() > 0);
```